Format the output of an association such that each key-value pair has its own line, and a few other conditions
I want to format the output of an association such that each key-value pair gets has its own line, and the keys are aligned together on the left, and the values are aligned together on the right. TableForm seems to do nothing to the association, and it only works with separated Keys and Values, but because the keys and values are each lists themselves, TableForm separates each list element within the keys and values in a way that is unnecessary for what I am trying to do. I would consider either a solution which produces this output in a text file or in Mathematica's output acceptable for my needs.

Have you tried using Dataset[<your association>]?

Thank you. I didn't know about the Dataset function, and the output is a bit different than what I imagined, but this should be readable to any collaborators, which is my most important goal.

Try: TableForm[Transpose[{Keys[assoc], Values[assoc]}]]
